# creating a python module using ctypes

Tags: python, pip, ctypes, python-module

I have a C library with only two functions: `char *foo_decode(const char*)` and `const char *foo_version()`.

I now want to create a python module that allows to call these two functions.

The C library is compiled into `foo.so`.

This is my python module file:

```
$ cat foo.py
import ctypes as ct

_lib = ct.cdll.LoadLibrary("./foo.so")
_lib.foo_decode.argtypes = [ct.c_char_p]
_lib.foo_decode.restype = ct.c_char_p
_lib.foo_version.argtypes = []
_lib.foo_version.restype = ct.c_char_p

def decode(fooText):
    return _lib.foo_decode(fooText.encode('utf8')).decode('utf-8')
    
def version():
    return _lib.foo_version().decode('utf-8')
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://pgi-jcns.fz-juelich.de/portal/pages/using-c-from-python.html).

When I start a python3 interpreter and execute this manually. Everything works fine.
I can call the functions and I get back the expected result.

But when I import my module file (`import foo`) I get the error `ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_foo)`.

What is happening and what should I do to fix this problem ?

My goal is to produce a package downloadable with pip install. Am I on the right track ? I don’t want wheels since the code is small and has no dependencies. I should thus compile fast and should be very portable.

Comment: As an aside, the `global` statements are completely unnecessary and you should delete them.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I removed the `global _lib`. Thank you

Comment: In this type of situations the dynamic module name starts with an underscore: *\_foo.so*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a shared library `foo.so` and a module `foo.py`. When Python does `import foo` it loads only one of them; in your case it's `foo.so`; but `foo.so` is not a Python module hence the error.

Rename your `foo.py` to something different like `foo_wrapper.py` and try `import foo_wrapper`.

Comment: This works. Thank you very much. I was a bit quick when generating the .so file. Normally, .so files are named `libfoo.so`. This would have avoided the confusion. I prefer to call the module `foo`.

Comment: Sure, all names are up to you. Just don't confuse Python's import with identical names. :-)